# MIXED_DML_OPERATION: DML in flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a record triggered flow on user that shares an record with the user. When I tried activating and deactivating the user to test I had this error :

`This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: MIXED_DML_OPERATION: DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): AccountShare, original object: User.`

So I added a condition on the flow to only execute when the flow is active. Now I can deactivate the user but I still get the same error when trying to activate it.

here is my flow :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add create/update/modify a user and a non-Setup object, such as an Account or AccountShare, etc, in the same transaction. Use an asynchronous path to perform the create/update:

[image: Asynchronous Update of non-Setup records]

Comment: I get this when trying to activate the flow : `These issues prevent activation.
$Record - For a path that runs asynchronously, configure the flow to run only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements or select the Is Changed operator in a condition.`

Comment: @Meryem You'll have to add a condition then; that seems reasonable. After all, you can check if you're activating a user, etc. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do specifically, this was kind of a general answer. You may want to go with a Pause element instead?